# Monaco Editor : How to fix certain line in source code

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

How can I set a line fixed in [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/)  ?

One can edit the content before or after the fixed line.
But she cannot edit or remove the fixed line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to lock (aka. read-only) individual lines. You can only set the entire editor to read-only.